# Php echo shows the br tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, line-breaks

I have an HTML form. When you click on the submit button it stores the data from the boxes into a table and then displays a message. the message is sent from a PHP file then it is displayed by js in an HTML file. The problem is that the message has `br` tags in it and when the message is displayed it shows the `<br>` tag instead of breaking the line.

This is where i am testing it - http://ft5.cu.cc/ Click on the heart logo to see the form.

**HTML FORM**

```
<div class="contact">
            <form method="post" action="daalo.php">
                <input type="text" maxlength="30" class="text" name="ign" id="ign" placeholder="Please type your IGN(In Game Name)" required="required"/>
                <input type="email" maxlength="30" class="required email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Please type your email" required="required"/><span class="status"></span>
                <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                <td><input type="text" maxlength="30" class="text" id="steamid" name="steamid" placeholder="Enter your Steam ID" required="required"/></td>
                <td><span class="status">
                <img id="tick" alt="Good"src="images/tick.png" width="16" height="16"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <span id="cross">Steam Id Already Added</span>
                </span>
                <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
            </form>
            <div id="loading">Processing your <b>WHITELIST</b> entry....</div>
        <div id="success"></div>
    </div>
```

****Php Insert****

```
<?php
include('connecti.php'); //Ganja Login


 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

//Insert
$lab1='IGN<br>'; 
$lab2='Email ID<br>'; 
$lab3='Steam ID<br>';
$lab4='Submitted.';
$lab5='Whitelist is updated everyday at 8pm (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris.';

$sql="INSERT INTO rusty_whitelist (name, email, steamid) VALUES ('$_POST[ign]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[steamid]')";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
    echo $lab1;
    echo $lab2;
    echo $lab3;
    echo $lab4;
    echo $lab5;

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

**Java Script**

```
(function($) {
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var thisForm = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
        $("#loading").fadeIn(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: thisForm.attr("action"),
                data: thisForm.serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#loading").fadeOut(function(){
                        $("#success").text(data).fadeIn();
                     });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
$('.md-trigger').tipsy({gravity: 's'});
})(jQuery);

$(function(){
  $().ready(function() {
    $('#videobg').tubular({videoId: 'tDvBwPzJ7dY'}); // where idOfYourVideo is the YouTube ID.
  });
});
```

Comment: I cleaned up your question to format things properly. Please read about [how to format your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Anyway, I don't think you have given us nearly enough information about how you are displaying this. We can't answer it because you haven't shown us any code.

Comment: yeah i am tryin to put that in now its not letting me.
i tried  this way also
'$lab1='IGN<br>';'
'$lab2='Email ID<br>';'

and then after the insert

'echo $lab1;'
'echo $lab2;'

Comment: i posted it in the comments but it looks like it didn't come up properly and its not letting me edit it any more

Comment: That's not the code I'm talking about. I'm talking about the PHP that does the output and the JS that processes it.

Comment: Educated guess: You are either escaping `<` or you are setting the `nodeValue` or `textContent` property instead of the (proprietary) `innerHTML` property.

Comment: I'm not going to visit a Website. Your posted code checks out. You could try using double quotes `$lab1="IGN<br>";` but I doubt this will make any difference. Show your code or will vote to close otherwise.

Comment: ok it was very easy to put the code sry i am stupid. anyway there it is

Comment: tried double quotes didnt work

Comment: If that is your actual code, you're missing a `<` for your `div class="contact">` but... I doubt it and think you may have made a typo.

Comment: Sidenote: You're also [`Open to SQL injection`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) for your DB; use prepared statements.

Comment: lol yes i made a mistake while copying it for here. the website is running. although ur browser might say its a phishing site cuz of the domain. ft5.cu.cc

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fft5.cu.cc%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is how you are using the value returned by Ajax into your code. Instead of using the jQuery `.text()` method, try the `.html()` method.

Comment: $("#success").html(data).fadeIn(); 
thanks this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected in my comment, you are setting the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) of an element object (or the DOM Level 2 equivalent of that) by means of jQuery's [`text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

You need to call the [`html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead to set the `innerHTML` property (or the equivalent of that).